# DataBinding ProgressBar progess is null

Tags: android, android-progressbar, android-databinding

I'm trying to set the progress of ProgressBar using data binding.

Here is my layout:

```
<data>
    <import type="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <variable
        name="sectionsViewModel"
        type="com.techiespace.projects.hark.SectionsViewModel" />
</data>
<!--Other views-->
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
      android:id="@+id/bankcardId1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_margin="10dp"
      android:clickable="true"
      android:focusable="true"
      android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
      android:onClick="onClickSection1"
      app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/primary_light">

      <TextView
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:gravity="center"
          android:paddingLeft="30dp"
          android:paddingRight="30dp"
          android:text="1"
          android:textSize="144sp" />

      <ProgressBar
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
          android:max="100" 
          android:progress='@{Integer.parseInt(sectionsViewModel.getAccuracyLiveData[0].getAccuracy().split(" ")[1])}'
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    />
      <TextView
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text='@{sectionsViewModel.getAccuracyLiveData[0].getAccuracy().split(" ")[1]}' />
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
<!--Other views-->
```

The call to `sectionsViewModel.getAccuracyLiveData[0].getAccuracy().split(" ")[1]` returns an String accuracy score which I've changed into integer as setting String as progress gives the following error:

```
Found data binding errors.
****/ data binding error ****msg:Cannot find the setter for attribute 'android:progress' with parameter type java.lang.String on android.widget.ProgressBar.
file:C:\Users\Shubham Sahu\StudioProjects\Hark\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_sections.xml
loc:64:44 - 64:111
****\ data binding error ****
```

The `android:text="..."` attribute value in the second TextView is resolved and displayed correctly(I verified it by using a custom ProgressBar and putting the setProgress() call in try catch blocks). But it gives the following runtime error while resolving `android:progress="..."`

```
09-29 08:35:40.683 26771-26771/com.techiespace.projects.hark E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.techiespace.projects.hark, PID: 26771
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.techiespace.projects.hark/com.techiespace.projects.hark.SectionsActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to call observer method
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2584)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2666)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1493)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5769)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to call observer method
        at android.arch.lifecycle.ClassesInfoCache$MethodReference.invokeCallback(ClassesInfoCache.java:225)
        at android.arch.lifecycle.ClassesInfoCache$CallbackInfo.invokeMethodsForEvent(ClassesInfoCache.java:193)
        at android.arch.lifecycle.ClassesInfoCache$CallbackInfo.invokeCallbacks(ClassesInfoCache.java:184)
        at android.arch.lifecycle.ReflectiveGenericLifecycleObserver.onStateChanged(ReflectiveGenericLifecycleObserver.java:36)
        at android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry$ObserverWithState.dispatchEvent(LifecycleRegistry.java:354)
        at android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.forwardPass(LifecycleRegistry.java:292)
        at android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.sync(LifecycleRegistry.java:332)
        at android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.moveToState(LifecycleRegistry.java:137)
        at android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.handleLifecycleEvent(LifecycleRegistry.java:123)
        at android.arch.lifecycle.ReportFragment.dispatch(ReportFragment.java:121)
        at android.arch.lifecycle.ReportFragment.onStart(ReportFragment.java:81)
        at android.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:2260)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1007)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1153)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1135)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStart(FragmentManager.java:1985)
        at android.app.FragmentController.dispatchStart(FragmentController.java:163)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6627)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2541)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2666) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1493) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5769) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679) 
     Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "null"
        at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:358)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:334)
        at com.techiespace.projects.hark.databinding.ActivitySectionsBindingImpl.executeBindings(ActivitySectionsBindingImpl.java:224)
        at android.databinding.ViewDataBinding.executeBindingsInternal(ViewDataBinding.java:437)
        at android.databinding.ViewDataBinding.executePendingBindings(ViewDataBinding.java:409)
        at android.databinding.ViewDataBinding$OnStartListener.onStart(ViewDataBinding.java:1621)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at android.arch.lifecycle.ClassesInfoCache$MethodReference.invokeCallback(ClassesInfoCache.java:215)
        at android.arch.lifecycle.ClassesInfoCache$CallbackInfo.invokeMethodsForEvent(ClassesInfoCache.java:193) 
        at android.arch.lifecycle.ClassesInfoCache$CallbackInfo.invokeCallbacks(ClassesInfoCache.java:184) 
        at android.arch.lifecycle.ReflectiveGenericLifecycleObserver.onStateChanged(ReflectiveGenericLifecycleObserver.java:36) 
        at android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry$ObserverWithState.dispatchEvent(LifecycleRegistry.java:354) 
        at android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.forwardPass(LifecycleRegistry.java:292) 
        at android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.sync(LifecycleRegistry.java:332) 
        at android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.moveToState(LifecycleRegistry.java:137) 
        at android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.handleLifecycleEvent(LifecycleRegistry.java:123) 
        at android.arch.lifecycle.ReportFragment.dispatch(ReportFragment.java:121) 
        at android.arch.lifecycle.ReportFragment.onStart(ReportFragment.java:81) 
        at android.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:2260) 
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1007) 
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1153) 
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1135) 
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStart(FragmentManager.java:1985) 
        at android.app.FragmentController.dispatchStart(FragmentController.java:163) 
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6627) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2541) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2666) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1493) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5769) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
```

I don't understand why the value is null while setting the progress while the TextView's text attribute rightly displays a non-null value.

Edit 1:
SectionsViewModel.java

```
public class SectionsViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    private LiveData<List<Clips>> accuracyLiveData;

    public SectionsViewModel(@NonNull Application application, String vidId) {
        super(application);
        ClipsDao clipsDao = ClipDatabase.getDatabase(application).clipsDao();
        accuracyLiveData = clipsDao.findLiveAccById(vidId);
    }

    public LiveData<List<Clips>> getAccuracyLiveData() {
        return accuracyLiveData;
    }
}
```

Edit 2: Activity

```
public class SectionsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String stopPoints;
    String videoId;
    String[] stopPointsArr;
    Intent intent;
    String originalXMLTranscript = "";

    ActivitySectionsBinding sectionsActivityBinding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sections);
        videoId = getIntent().getStringExtra("id");
        stopPoints = getIntent().getStringExtra("stop_points");
        originalXMLTranscript = getIntent().getStringExtra("xml_transcript");
        stopPointsArr = stopPoints.split(" ");
        intent = new Intent(this, EvaluateClipActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("id", videoId);
        intent.putExtra("xml_transcript", originalXMLTranscript);
        SectionsViewModel sectionsViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, new SectionsViewModelFactory(this.getApplication(), videoId)).get(SectionsViewModel.class);
        sectionsActivityBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_sections);
        sectionsActivityBinding.setLifecycleOwner(this);
        sectionsActivityBinding.setSectionsViewModel(sectionsViewModel);
        setContentView(sectionsActivityBinding.getRoot());
    }
}
```

Comment: @MeosCoder I've added the code. `getAccuracy()` is a getter for accuracy in the `Clips` class. `accuracy` is a String of space separated integer values.

Comment: share your activity class.

Comment: @pskink yes I noticed it. My question is why is it null for `progress` but not null(as expected) for `text`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I debugged the code by adding breakpoints in ActivitySectionsBindingImpl.java
The code in this file is called twice for some reason.
The first time the call to `sectionsViewModelGetAccuracyLiveData.getValue()` function in the file returns null and hence the subsequent code is not executed.
In the end there is a parseInt call without checking if the value passed in is valid. This is where the error occurs.

The reason why the app didn't crash when accessing the same data in the TextView was that all functions are checked to be not-null except the Integer.parseInt() function.

Here is a part of the generated ActivitySectionsBindingImpl.java file before the fix.

```
if (sectionsViewModel != null) {
    // read sectionsViewModel.getAccuracyLiveData
    sectionsViewModelGetAccuracyLiveData = sectionsViewModel.getAccuracyLiveData();
}
updateLiveDataRegistration(0, sectionsViewModelGetAccuracyLiveData);


if (sectionsViewModelGetAccuracyLiveData != null) {
    // read sectionsViewModel.getAccuracyLiveData.getValue()
    sectionsViewModelGetAccuracyLiveDataGetValue = sectionsViewModelGetAccuracyLiveData.getValue();
}


if (sectionsViewModelGetAccuracyLiveDataGetValue != null) {
    // read sectionsViewModel.getAccuracyLiveData.getValue()[0]
    sectionsViewModelGetAccuracyLiveData0 = getFromList(sectionsViewModelGetAccuracyLiveDataGetValue, 0);
}


if (sectionsViewModelGetAccuracyLiveData0 != null) {
    // read sectionsViewModel.getAccuracyLiveData.getValue()[0].getAccuracy()
    sectionsViewModelGetAccuracyLiveData0GetAccuracy = sectionsViewModelGetAccuracyLiveData0.getAccuracy();
}


if (sectionsViewModelGetAccuracyLiveData0GetAccuracy != null) {
    // read sectionsViewModel.getAccuracyLiveData.getValue()[0].getAccuracy().split(" ")
    sectionsViewModelGetAccuracyLiveData0GetAccuracySplitJavaLangString = sectionsViewModelGetAccuracyLiveData0GetAccuracy.split(" ");
}


if (sectionsViewModelGetAccuracyLiveData0GetAccuracySplitJavaLangString != null) {
    // read sectionsViewModel.getAccuracyLiveData.getValue()[0].getAccuracy().split(" ")[6]
    sectionsViewModelGetAccuracyLiveData0GetAccuracySplit6 = getFromArray(sectionsViewModelGetAccuracyLiveData0GetAccuracySplitJavaLangString, 6);
    // read sectionsViewModel.getAccuracyLiveData.getValue()[0].getAccuracy().split(" ")[1]
    sectionsViewModelGetAccuracyLiveData0GetAccuracySplit1 = getFromArray(sectionsViewModelGetAccuracyLiveData0GetAccuracySplitJavaLangString, 1);
    // read sectionsViewModel.getAccuracyLiveData.getValue()[0].getAccuracy().split(" ")[4]
    sectionsViewModelGetAccuracyLiveData0GetAccuracySplit4 = getFromArray(sectionsViewModelGetAccuracyLiveData0GetAccuracySplitJavaLangString, 4);
    // read sectionsViewModel.getAccuracyLiveData.getValue()[0].getAccuracy().split(" ")[7]
    sectionsViewModelGetAccuracyLiveData0GetAccuracySplit7 = getFromArray(sectionsViewModelGetAccuracyLiveData0GetAccuracySplitJavaLangString, 7);
    // read sectionsViewModel.getAccuracyLiveData.getValue()[0].getAccuracy().split(" ")[2]
    sectionsViewModelGetAccuracyLiveData0GetAccuracySplit2 = getFromArray(sectionsViewModelGetAccuracyLiveData0GetAccuracySplitJavaLangString, 2);
    // read sectionsViewModel.getAccuracyLiveData.getValue()[0].getAccuracy().split(" ")[5]
    sectionsViewModelGetAccuracyLiveData0GetAccuracySplit5 = getFromArray(sectionsViewModelGetAccuracyLiveData0GetAccuracySplitJavaLangString, 5);
    // read sectionsViewModel.getAccuracyLiveData.getValue()[0].getAccuracy().split(" ")[3]
    sectionsViewModelGetAccuracyLiveData0GetAccuracySplit3 = getFromArray(sectionsViewModelGetAccuracyLiveData0GetAccuracySplitJavaLangString, 3);
}


// read Integer.parseInt(sectionsViewModel.getAccuracyLiveData.getValue()[0].getAccuracy().split(" ")[1])
integerParseIntSectionsViewModelGetAccuracyLiveData0GetAccuracySplit1 = java.lang.Integer.parseInt(sectionsViewModelGetAccuracyLiveData0GetAccuracySplit1);
```

Fix
In my xml file is simply added a null check

`android:progress= '@{sectionsViewModel.getAccuracyLiveData[0].getAccuracy().split(" ")[1] != null ? (int)Double.parseDouble(sectionsViewModel.getAccuracyLiveData[0].getAccuracy().split(" ")[1]) : 50}'`

Although this solves the problem, I don't fully understand why is ActivitySectionsBindingImpl.java called twice.